# httpd.serve_forever Does not keep server running

Tags: python, http, socketserver

I have an HTTP server and every time I add a function or add a print mechanism
it Brings me an error. For example in this Situation I am trying to have a management console and I go to the URL of the server and well nothing but a cannot connect in Google Chrome.

Does it only accept just the http.serve_forever()? Or is it possible to have a management console after the console has started. Because that is what I am trying to do. But there is no URL to view the HTTP Server. Meaning httpd.serve_forever() does not function properly in my view.  Is there any way to fix this?

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import os
#Create Login System at (10:30)

# Create Management Console
def Management():
commands = ["info", "exit", "openurl","restart","login"]
usr_input = input("> ")
if usr_input == commands[0]:
    print("The Port Running for this server is: ", PORT)
    print("The URL of the server is: ", HOST, PORT)

if usr_input == commands[1]:
    exit_verify = input("Are you sure?: Y/N")
    if exit_verify == "Y" or "y":
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid Response...")
        Management()

    if exit_verify == "N" or "n":
        Management()

if usr_input == commands[2]:
    URL = "start"
    URL = url+Address
    os.system(URL)
# If cmd opens close window after opening URL

else:
    Management()

if usr_input == commands[3]:
# Note to Readme as the server needs to be stored on "C:\" Directory
    os.system("start F:\Python36\httpserver.py")
    os.system("exit")
    exit()
else: 
    Management()





HOST = input("Your IP Address: ")
PORT = 8080

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), Handler)
Management()
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: You should include what errors you get

Comment: You do have a few logical/syntax errors. For example, code isn't intended properly and the if statements aren't written properly  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values

Comment: I understand that, but that couldn't interfere with the functionality of the method serve_forever() could it?

Comment: Here is my error upon running the program: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 8-9: truncated \uXXXX escape

Comment: I would suggest you make a [mcve] in the question. Only show the  command conditional that causes the error. Please [edit] your question accordingly

Comment: By the way, you aren't even using  any information from the httpd socket, so that's not the problem